# Reordering octopus steps through powershell script

Tags: powershell

I want to automate my power shell script to reorder steps in octopus project in-spite of going to octopus process and then use the reorder option. Is this possible ? Can we reorder steps of octopus project process through power shell script?

Comment: yes you can, what have you tried?

Comment: can you show how, just want to know how it can be done?

Comment: get the process from the api, modify it and upload it back

Comment: https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/api#rest-api-documentation-via-swagger

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service - you've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you include these basics.